# Use of less in different places

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Is there any difference between uses of “less” in sentences below in terms of meaning. I mean use “less” in different place in sentences change the meaning ? Or Are word forms of them different from eachother?

1) He smoked less cigarette than me .

2)He smoked cigarette less than me .

3) He smoked less than me .

Comment: You might be interested in the debate over **less** vs **fewer**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fewer_versus_less

Answer (score 1):

> 1) He smoked fewer cigarette**s** than me.

This refers to the quantity of cigarettes, e.g., if on a particular day, he smoked 5, but you smoked 10.

Also, for this reason - that of us discussing a quantity of items, as opposed to something singular - the correct word is "fewer", although "less" can be just as, if not more(!), idiomatic.

> 2) He smoked cigarette**s** less than me.

This refers more to the frequency of how often you smoke. It's more general, and isn't referring directly the number of cigarettes, but instead to how often you generally smoke cigarettes. It refers to "smoking cigarettes" as an activity.

> 3) He smoked less than me.

This is the same as 2), except that you are not specifying what you are smoking, but just talking about smoking in general.

Comment: To be strictly correct, (1) should be "He smoked _fewer_ cigarettes than _I did_.

Comment: Interesting, will update my answer - thanks!

Comment: It can also be 1) He smoked **lesser** cigarettes than me.

Comment: @Boris, "lesser" in that case would describe some deficiency in quality, i.e. his cigarettes weren't as good in some way.